# Outputting JSON data from an object in an array. Pug (Jade)

Tags: html, arrays, json, object, pug

Outputting JSON data from an object in an array. 
I use **Pug** (Jade).

I'm trying like this:

```
h1.main-title.center Changelog
    each log in changelog
      .changelog-item
        .second-title 
          span= log['ver']
          span.text-hide= log['date']
        .changelog-item__log
          .row
            .col-xs-3
              span.label.label--success= log.do['title']
            .col-xs-9
              span= log.do['text']
```

Json:

```
{
  "log1": {
    "ver" : "1.0.0",
    "date" : " - 31 July 2018",
    "do" : [

      {
        "label" : ".label--success ",
        "title" : "Add",
        "text" : "Changelog Page"
      },
      {
        "label" : ".label--danger ",
        "title" : "Fixed",
        "text" : "Navbar"
      }
    ]
  },
  "log2": {
    "ver" : "1.0.2",
    "date" : " - 31 July 2018",
    "do" : [

      {
        "label" : ".label--success ",
        "title" : "Add something",
        "text" : "Changelog Page something"
      },
      {
        "label" : ".label--danger ",
        "title" : "Fixed something",
        "text" : "Navbar something"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Displays only **ver** and **date**.

log.do['text'] and log.do['title'] is not working.

but simple objects is working well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`do` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) in javascript. Try renaming that property to something like "actions".